# Energy Bands Question

Tags: semiconductor-physics, conductors, electronic-band-theory

When an electron passes into the valence band, is it no longer useful for conduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer "no", but it depends what you mean. An electron going from the conduction to the valence band eliminates both a conduction band electron and a valence band hole. Both helped with conduction, and now you've gotten rid of them. Thus, conduction would go down.

This can be explained another way. To quote Ashcroft and Mermin: "Conduction is due only to those electrons that are found in partially filled bands" (Chapter 12, section "Inertness of Filled Bands"). This is because in a filled band, for every electron with a wave vector $\vec{k}$, there will be another electron with wave vector $-\vec{k}$, and the current due to one cancels out the current due to the other. There can only be conduction when one of those two electrons is missing.

In your situation, I assume that you are dealing with a "normal" semiconductor, so the valence band is already nearly full, and by adding another electron to the valence band, you are making the valence band even fuller.** Thus, all things being equal, I would expect that adding an electron to the valence band would reduce the conduction of your system.

The above explanations are equivalent.

** Note that this is a fine point. Adding an electron to the conduction band also makes the conduction band fuller, but conduction goes up because the band is mostly empty. Adding electrons increases conduction for nearly empty bands and decreases it for nearly full bands. This is covered in Ashcroft and Mermin but is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons will still participate in conduction once in the valence band. Conduction in the valence band is caused by the movement of *holes* - which is essentially the movement of electrons into the vacancies left by those promoted to the conduction band.